# symfony Form validation ignores messages

Tags: php, validation, symfony

SectionsType class

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('description')
    ;

}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Acm\StoreBundle\Entity\Sections'
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'acm_storebundle_sections';
}
```

Validation.yml:

```
Acm\StoreBundle\Entity\Sections:
properties:
    name:
        - NotBlank: 
            message: not.valid
        - Length:
            min: 3
            max: 45
```

also i've tried

```
Acm\StoreBundle\Entity\Sections:
properties:
    name:
        - NotBlank: {message: "not.valid" }
        - Length:
            min: 3
            max: 45
```

validators.{lang}.yml:

```
    <body>
        <trans-unit id="1">
            <source>not.valid</source>
            <target> enter a valid name</target>
        </trans-unit>

    </body>
```

config.yml

```
validation:       { enabled: true }
```

and i tried

```
validation:      { enabled: true, enable_annotations: true }
```

and

```
validation:      { enabled: true, enable_annotations: false }
```

and

```
validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
```

the problem is the validator shows "Please fill out this field." message with empty entries and ignore my messages from Validation.yml file

any idea ?

Comment: is your yml file called validation? If is, its wrong. The name must be validators. Try to clean the cache too

Answer (score 0):

solution is to add "novalidate" to disable the html5 validation

```
{{ form(form, {'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}
```